# Digital Filters

Tags: signal-analysis, filters

Can somebody help with the constructing filter by amplitude and phase spectrum? Is it possible? 
I try to google it, but unsuccessufully.
I have some thoughts about solving it by system of linear equations or something like this. This is true way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa093/sloa093.pdf